# Why generate resource names in OpenGL and DevIL?

Tags: c++, devil

Just reading the DevIL manual [here](http://openil.sourceforge.net/docs/DevIL%20Manual.pdf). Also reminded me of [glGenBuffers](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml). Why did they choose to have the user of each library *generate* names (pg. 6 in the DevIL manual), rather than specifying names for your own images/buffers and so on?

I thought maybe they're trying to keep things simpler, automation-wise, for when you need to load large batches of images. But I'm not sure that's a sensible conclusion. Probably there's some incredibly straightforward answer that I will smack myself on the forehead for not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/vertex_buffer_objects/22002/):

> The process is as follows: first, use glGenBuffersARB to get a valid
>   VBO "name". Essentially, a name is an ID number which OpenGL will
>   associate with your data. We want to generate a name because the same
>   ones won't always be available.